# Unable to get desired Text Response from API

Tags: php, api, curl, text

Here's my API Format:

```
http://api.example.com/balance.php?format=#format&token=#token

//Output text

#username|#balance|#error_code|#resText
```

Here's my PHP Codes:

```
<?php

$url="http://api.example.com/balance.php?format=text&token=ExAmPlEToKeN";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);


$output = curl_exec($ch);  

$balance = $output; /* Help me here to get the balance from the response */  

curl_close($ch);    

echo "Balance is:".$balance;

?>
```

This shows:

> Balance is: my_username|500.00|0|Success

But I need to show only the balance like this:

> Balance is: 500.00

Please help me!

Comment: Explode by `|` and get what you need.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm not familiar with these.. @u_mulder

Comment: Make an effort and use your excellent solving skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like u_mulder said use the explode() function

```
$balance="my_username|500.00|0|Success" ;
$ar =explode ('|', $balance);
$amount =$ar [1];
echo "Balance is:".$amount;
```

I splitted code for clarity, but you can compress it to a single line if you want to.